# VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount returns wrong count Wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
  <ListBox x:Name="my_list" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,34,0,10">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <CheckBox x:Name="cbx_state"  Tag="{Binding}" Checked="cbx_state_Checked" Unchecked="cbx_state_Unchecked" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txt_string" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="34" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txt_string1" Text=" Text " VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" />
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I have binded the listbox with a list containing items more then 10.What i did is on application bar menu item click i wanted to check all the checkbox .But this method i have implemented have different behavior.Sometimes the child count is returned less then the actual count.Method is :

```
 private void GetItemsRecursive(DependencyObject lb)
    {
        var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(lb);

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lb, i);

            if (child is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox targeted_element = (CheckBox)child;

                targeted_element.IsChecked = true;

                if (targeted_element.IsChecked == true)
                {

                    return;
                }
            }

            GetItemsRecursive(child);
        }
    }
```

I am getting childrenCount as different value every time and therefore resulting in leaving some check boxes as unchecked.

Comment: what do you imagine this code does?

Comment: it checks all the checkboxes under listbox

Comment: You might get your code working, but there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do. (checking if any item in list is checked? ). I would recommend reading about MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox` uses a virtualizing container. What that means is that the items are loaded only when they're needed (more or less just before showing on the screen).

What you can to is change the default `Listbox.ItemsPanel` to `StackPanel`

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

However, that might hurt the performance of your app, especially in the case of long lists. You're already using bindings for your checkboxes. The best solution would be to rely on MVVM - add a Checked-binding and instead of calling `GetItemsRecursive` execute a command on the `ViewModel` that sets the List-ViewModel checked property.